# Fastest way to pick out data

Tags: performance, matlab, indexing

I am programming a function which should be able to integrate a function between a and b. The catch is that the function is only provided by a data array with corresponding time points.

The problem is that when a lower and upper limit I have to cut out the part of the data vector that lies within this timeframe - and my question is, how is this done the most efficient?

What I am doing now is the following:

```
llim = find(time==lima); 
ulim = find(time==limb);

data = data(llim:ulim); 
int1 = h/2*(data(1) + data(end) + 2*sum(data(2:end)));
```

But according to the profiler 50-something % are used on the first 3 lines, so if that could be reduced it would be great.

I have also tried using

```
data = data(time>=lima & time<=limb);
```

but that is not faster. Any suggestions?

Comment: don't you mean `data = data(time>=lima & time<=limb)`? `lima` is less than `limb` right?

Comment: Maybe split up the option you tried? It shouldn't make a difference, but who knows? `data = data(time >= lima); data = data(time <= limb);`

Comment: @Dan You are completely right. I just quickly retyped it to say that I had tried it.

Comment: @Swier So the problem is that if I do that, then every point in the vector is checked if it is first larger than lima and then smaller than limb. However my time vector is sorted, so once I know the points llim and ulim, then I know that I want every point in-between.

Comment: @bla My dataset is small ~1000 entries, but the function is called a a lot of times ~5e6

Comment: @NickyMattsson the first check removes everything smaller than `lima`, before the check on `limb`. But it still should perform roughly as fast as what you tried, which should be much better than `find`. Maybe figure out a way of running it fewer times? If the limits are the same for many of the arrays you could possibly stick them together and run the test once. Array comparisons scale really well with array size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottom line, the logical condition line wins. Here's an analysis for a 1e3 length vector with random time differences:

```
N=1e3;
data=rand(1,N);

time=1:N;
for n=1:100

    li=sort(randi(N,2,1)) ;

    llim = find(time==li(1));
    ulim = find(time==li(2));

    f1 = @() data( find(time==li(1)): find(time==li(2)));
    f2 = @() data(time>=li(1) & time<=li(2));
    d(n)=diff(li);
    t1(n)=timeit(f1);
    t2(n)=timeit(f2);
end

%%
plot(d,t1,'s',d,t2,'o');
xlabel('llim-ulim');
ylabel('time (sec)');
legend('find method','logical cond method');
```

[image]